# associated record is nil for one user but not for the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

i got a simple messaging system running between two users.
the user who is creating a `conversation` gets a record i can access via `User.find(sender_id).conversation.last`, the recipient however gets a => nil if i try to access `User.find(recipient_id).conversation.last` (ofc i replaced recipient_id and sender_id with the actual id).

However, both user get the messages associated with the conversation and can chat. I am using foreign keys according to the tutorial of [Dana Mulder on Medium](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1). i think this is weird because i expect that both users ( the reciever and the sender ) should be able to access the record for the conversation they are into. is there a way to achieve that?

my models:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :messages, through: :conversations
```

**Conversation.rb**

```
belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
```

**Message.rb**

```
belongs_to :conversation
belongs_to :user
```

the conversations controller:
**conversations_controller.rb**

```
def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
     @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
   else
     @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
   end
   redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end
```

do you have an idea how to make the conversation accessible for both users? (it is accessible but not in the way i need it to).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your user association with conversations is only looking for `sender_id`

```
has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id, dependent: :destroy
```

The recipient user is looking for conversation with his id as `sender_id` and not as `recipient_id`.

I think you can fix that by adding a join model between users and conversations instead of a conversation just belonging to a sender and a recipient (though you should save those references anyway).

Something like

```
class ConversationsUsers < ....
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class User < ...
  has_many :conversations_users
  has_many :conversations, through: :conversations_users
  has_many :started_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :received_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: :recipient_id
end

class Conversation < ...
  has_many :convesations_users
end
```

For each Conversation you'll have two records on conversations_users table, one for each user. Now both users can query all the conversations independant of being a sender or a recipient (and you can have any number of participants on a conversation too if you plan to extend it!).

You'll have to create some records manually though, after creating a Conversation you could have an after callback to create two conversation_user object one for each user.

---

Another option is to just use a method

```
def conversations
  Conversation.where(sender_id: id).or(Conversation.where(recipient_id: id))
end
```

but you won't be able to use joins/includes/etc.

EDIT: To get all messages, add another method:

```
def messages
  conv_ids = conversations.pluck(:id)
  Message.where(conversation_id: conv_ids)
end
```

then you can this to get all read messages for example

```
current_user.messages.where(read: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response again. I want to keep it as lightweight as possible because i already got a ton of models and stuff. Ill try option 2 soon.

Comment: The method did the job partially. i am now able to access the conversations through every user involved but unfortunately this just works for the conversations and not for the associated messages. i would need something like `Conversation.where(sender_id: id).or(Conversation.where(recipient_id: id)).messages.where(read: true)`

Comment: You can do it with 2 steps (2 queries): `conv_ids = conversations.pluck(:id); Message.where(conversation_id: conv_ids, read: true)`

Comment: where do i place `conv_ids = conversations.pluck(:id);` ? just under the `conversations` method will give me an error `undefined local variable or method `conversations' for User`

Comment: check my edit, it should be another method, since `conversations` is not defined yet

Comment: BLODDY HELL YOU DID IT! thank you very much arieljoud. you havent helped me out for the first time. im glad there are skilled coders like you are so i can learn more and more.